# Is there a way to clone a private git repo inside ec2 instance when creating the instance using Terraform?

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an ec2 instance with Terraform and want to clone a git repository inside the ec2 instance while launching it using Terraform. Is there a way to do it? Doing a git clone is not working and I am getting access denied(public key) error.

Comment: When you say "doing a git clone is not working", are you running it manually on the instance, or via the User Data script? What do you mean by "private git repo" -- are you providing the required credentials, since it is private? What command are you running when you receive the error? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to do a git clone. You can do it from the user data but need to do a few things:

- Make sure git is installed and configure
- If you are using SSH then you need to setup your private key, typically you store it in the SSM parameter store of AWS Secrets Manager and give your EC2 role permissions to access it.

  - Then you can clone your repo.

Another approach would be to copy your repo to S3, and then just access what you need from there.